# Какой максимум размер информации будет хранится в базе данных

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server, хранение-данных

Здравствуйте.

Допустим, я создал сайт, используя любую базу данных. Пользователи будут загружать видео, фото и т. д. Где будут храниться эти данные и какой максимум объем памяти будет использоваться? Понимаю, что вопрос может быть некорректным, но не получается найти ответ.

Comment: Ну это от вас зависит. И какое отношение имеет база данных к фото и видео, их все таки в файлах лучше хранить

Comment: объем какой памяти? оперативной? дисковой?

Comment: для хранения файлов у вас три пути 1) бинарные поля 2) файлстрим 3) файловые таблицы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если речь идёт о памяти на диске: данные будут храниться там, куда ты их запишешь, на диск - на диске, в базу данных - в базе данных.
Если речь идёт об оперативной памяти: разные субд занимают разное количество памяти.

Занимаемая память ограничена только железом(жестким диском/оперативной памятью)

Comment: Andrei .то есть загружаемые пользователем на сайт медиа файлы будут хранится либо в базе данных ,либо у меня на жестком диске?

Comment: Да, в зависимости от того как будет прописана обработка в самом приложении, оно, например, может писать файлы в одну базу, все остальные данные в другую.

Comment: ясно .спасибо спасли от мучений.